# Timeout na função input do Python

Tags: python

```
teste = input('Olá qual o seu nome?')
```

Como executar algo se o usuário demorar mais que um determinado intervalo de tempo para responder ao input?

Exemplo:

- Escrever na tela `Você demorou demais`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A função `signal.alarm` está disponível apenas para ambiente Unix.

Você pode utilizar o módulo [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html). Primeiro, definimos uma função que tratará o caso de o usuário estar inativo e o seu tempo expirar. Para simplificar, irei apenas disparar uma exceção:

```
def timeout():
    raise Exception('Seu tempo acabou!')
```

Finalmente, a mágica. Com o módulo `signal`, definimos um sinal de tempo em que a função `timeout` será responsável por processar. Fazemos isso simplesmente com:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout)
```

E, então, fazemos:

```
try:
    signal.alarm(5)
    name = input('Qual é o seu nome? ')
    signal.alarm(0)
    print('Seja bem-vindo,', name)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Isto é, definimos o tempo de alarme do nosso sinal para 5 segundos, ou seja, a partir deste momento corridos 5 segundos, a função `timeout` será executada; tentamos fazer a leitura do nome do usuário e, se bem sucedida, cancelamos nosso sinal definindo o tempo de alarme para 0. Caso o usuário esteja inativo, o sinal não será cancelado e passados os 5 segundos, a função `timeout` será executada, disparando a exceção e, consequentemente, sendo capturada pelo `try`, encerando o programa.

O código completo ficaria:

```
import signal

def timeout(signum, frame):
    raise Exception('Seu tempo acabou!')

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout)
signal.alarm(5)

try:
    signal.alarm(5)
    name = input('Qual é o seu nome? ')
    signal.alarm(0)
    print('Seja bem-vindo,', name)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/HeftyLovingStructure) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/49e699bef9499880e20ba9185f656339)</sup>

Obviamente que você pode deixar tudo muito mais bonito implementando um decorador no Python. Por exemplo:

```
import signal

def timeout(seconds):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            def handler(signum, frame):
                raise Exception(f'Timeout of {function.__name__} function')
            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
            signal.alarm(seconds)
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)
            signal.alarm(0)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Assim, para definir o *timeout* de uma função qualquer, basta fazer:

```
@timeout(seconds=5)
def read_user_name():
    name = input('Qual é o seu nome? ')
    print('Seja bem-vindo,', name)
```

E utilizá-la com:

```
try:
    read_user_name()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Você pode, inclusive, utilizar em outras situações, tal como baixar um arquivo com o módulo `requests`:

```
@timeout(seconds=30)
def download_awesome_image(save):
    with open(save, 'wb') as stream:
        response = requests.get('http://url.to/awesome_image.jpg')
        stream.write(response.content)

try:
    download_awesome_image(save='awesome_image.jpg')
except Exception as e:
    print('Desculpe-me, mas demorou muito e eu não quis esperar')
```

## Windows e outros

Uma alternativa que funcione também no Windows é utilizar o módulo `multiprocessing`, definindo um processo distinto para executar a tarefa. De forma semelhante a anterior, podemos definir um decorador:

```
from multiprocessing import TimeoutError
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def timeout(seconds):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
            result = pool.apply_async(function, args=args, kwds=kwargs)
            try:
                return result.get(timeout=seconds)
            except TimeoutError as e:
                return e
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@timeout(5)
def read_user_name():
    return input('Nome? ')

name = read_user_name()

if isinstance(name, TimeoutError):
    print('Demorou demais, parsa!')
else:
    print('Olá', name)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/PoliteInfiniteComputer) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/3b74275be3d4063251796c615385cba5)</sup>

Perceba que, como a função será executada em outro processo, a exceção que é disparada ao expirar o tempo não influencia no processo original, então, para contornar isso, retornei a própria instância da exceção e fiz a verificação do tipo antes de tratar o valor da variável.

Comment: Cara, sensacional, esse decorator ficou um canivete suíço +1. Nota: signal não é totalmente compatível com todos sistemas, ao menos não com Windows. Algo que talvez funcione para Windows seria o https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer

Answer (score 1):

Tive essa duvida a um tempo atrás. A forma que achei foi essa.

```
import time

print('Pausa de 5 segundos (Aperte Ctrl-C para inserir algo)')
try:
    for i in range(0,5):
        time.sleep(1)    
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    input("Entrada: ")
```

Comment: Olha, para ser bem sincero, eu não consegui me decidir se eu gosto desta solução ou não, mas deixei meu voto pelo fato que é funcional e, para muitas aplicações seria viável aplicá-la pela simplicidade. Embora ainda é necessário colocar que existe a questão de o comando `Ctrl+C` não parar a execução do programa durante este tempo de espera. Você está alterando o comportamento natural da aplicação e isso pode gerar efeitos colaterais. Poderia adicionar isso à resposta?

Comment: O programa para a execução caso seja no console.