# Como fazer um timer no Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, timer

Tenho que fazer um timer que conte x segundos, mas que não fique em loop esperando o tempo passar, ao invez disso ele deve contar o tempo e gerar um evento ao encerrar a contagem do tempo pré definido.
Preciso saber se existe algum módulo em Python 3 que possa realizar essa função e que tenha um start e um resetar na contagem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim como citei na resposta abaixo

[Timeout na função input do Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/297721/5878)

Você pode utilizar o módulo `signal`, em sistemas Unix, para efetuar a chamada a uma função depois de um determinado tempo, sem bloquear a execução do programa principal.

```
import signal

def evento(*args):
    print("Evento disparado")

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, evento)
signal.alarm(5)

resposta = input('Por favor, aguarde 5 segundos...')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/DefinitiveBlueBrackets) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/14f8f5d46abf9432c5d2879b15018c9d)</sup>

Para Windows, você pode adaptar a solução que apresentei na outra resposta da mesma forma.