# multiplos comandos com python subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, arm

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema (trabalho da faculdade) que consiste em um site para o uso de uma determinada placa. O problema é que, para rodar o código na placa, preciso executar uma porção de comandos.

Atualmente meu código está assim:

```
def run():
    comando = "cd nke/NKE0.7e/Placa && make clean && make && sudo make ispu && cd .. && sudo ./terminal64"
    print(comando)
    # print(os.system(comando)
    process = subprocess.Popen(comando, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = process.communicate()
    print(out)
```

O problema é que o `terminal64` nunca termina (isso não é um erro), então eu precisaria setar um tempo pra ele rodar e matá-lo. Depois disso (exemplo, 2 minutos), pesquisei e pelo que entendi isso pode ser feito usando a biblioteca `subprocess`, porém não consegui executar o mesmo comando que executava no `os.system` nela.

Alguém pode me ajudar a implementar esse comando na `subprocess` ou a setar um *timeout* no `terminal64`?

Comment: Qual é a saída que você espera obter em `print(out)`, visto que o comando nunca finaliza? Já dei uma [sugestão de implementação de timeout](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/297727/5878) aqui no site caso queira estudá-la.

Comment: Olá @AndersonCarlosWoss o comando terminal monitora o codigo que vai rodar na placa e me dá uma serie de informações da mesma, porém após o codigo chegar ao final a placa entra em modo de espera e printa informações dispensáveis eternamente,assim que chegar em casa estudarei seu codigo mt obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O metodo [Popen.communicate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) tem um parâmetro, chamado timeout que faz exatamente o que você precisa, espera por n segundos e, caso o processo não tenha retornado, mata ele e dispara uma exceção TimeoutExpired. O código ficaria assim:

```
def run():
    comando = "cd nke/NKE0.7e/Placa && make clean && make && sudo make ispu && cd .. && sudo ./terminal64"

    process = subprocess.Popen(comando, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # espera por 2 minutos
    out, err = process.communicate(timeout=120) 
    print(out)
```