# Como fazer um timeout e reexecutar uma linha de comando em Python?

Tags: python, timeout

Tenho um requisição de informação que simplesmente não recebe informação e fica parado, então reenvio executo e tenho a resposta. Então, como fazer que a linha de comando seja cancelada depois de um limite de tempo e reexecutada até que um evento ocorra?

Exemplo:

```py
def atrasado():
    import random
    import time
    a = random.random()
    time.sleep(a*10)
    if a < 0.5:
        print('Foi')
        print(a*10)
    else:
        print('erro')
        print(a*10)
```

Então, como dar timeout em `atrasado()` se ele demorar mais de 5 segundos e reiniciar a função?

Há sempre a situação de `atrasado()` demorar mais de 5 segundos apesar de ter sido reiniciar.

Comment: Marcio, marquei como duplicata uma pergunta em que respondi como implementar o timeout. Se ficar com alguma dúvida ou achar que a resposta não lhe seja útil, por favor me avise.

Comment: @Woss melhorei a pergunta, pois só 'matar' o comando não me adianta, preciso que ele seja reexecutado.

Comment: É só colocar um teu/except dentro de um laço de repetição

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o [retry pattern](https://pypi.org/project/retry/) para executa sua função novamente.

O retry é um pattern utilizado em varias linguagem para refazer a chamada de uma função caso ocorra algum erro, na sua implementação você pode especificar o numero de tentativas que sua função terá para executar após esse numero de tentativas se ainda persistir o erro ela será finalizada e uma exceção será lançada

Sempre que presumirmos que uma resposta inesperada - ou nenhuma resposta nesse caso - pode ser corrigida enviando a solicitação novamente, o uso do padrão de repetição pode ajudar.

```
from retry import retry
@retry()
def make_trouble():
    '''Retry until succeed'''
```

Também existe outas bibliotecas como [timeout-decorator](https://pypi.org/project/timeout-decorator/) que você pode usar para limitar o tempo da sua função.

*timeout-decorator* também é um pattern usado para limitar o tempo de execução de uma função

O timeout pattern é bastante simples e muitos clientes HTTP têm um tempo limite padrão configurado. O objetivo é evitar tempos de espera ilimitados por respostas e, assim, tratar cada solicitação como falha quando nenhuma resposta foi recebida dentro do tempo limite.

```
import time
import timeout_decorator

@timeout_decorator.timeout(5)
def mytest():
    print("Start")
    for i in range(1,10):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("{} seconds have passed".format(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mytest()
```

Fora esse dois ainda existe alguns pattern que vem a calha de vez em quanto como o
[Circuit breaker](https://pypi.org/project/circuitbreaker/), [fallback](https://pypi.org/project/fallback-property/)

Sua função ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
from retry import retry
import random
import time


@retry(tries=3, delay=2)
def atrasado():
    a = random.random()
    time.sleep(a*10)
    if a < 0.5:
        print('Foi')
        print(a*10)
    else:
        print("Nova Tetativa")        
        raise Exception("Erro de tempo")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    atrasado()
```

Comment: Acho que sua resposta ficaria bem melhor se você desse uma explicada no que o `@retry()` faz

Comment: @yoyo, dei uma melhorada na explicação

Answer (score 3):

Como comentado, você pode utilizar a resposta de [Timeout na função input do Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/297727/5878) junto com um laço de repetição, assim re-executar a função quando ocorrer o timeout.

```py
@timeout(seconds=5)
def read_user_name():
    name = input('Qual é o seu nome? ')
    print('Seja bem-vindo,', name)

attempts = 5

while attempts:
    try:
        read_user_name()
        break
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        attempts -= 1
else:
    print('Erro: acabaram suas tentativas')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/NewUnfitJavadoc#main.py)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução para o seu problema é utilizar o módulo [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).
`asyncio` é uma biblioteca para escrever código concorrente assíncrono usando a sintaxe `async/await`.

`asyncio` opera sobre [*corrotinas*](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/glossary.html#term-coroutine) que são uma forma mais generalizada de sub-rotinas. Sub-rotinas tem a entrada iniciada em um ponto, e a saída em outro ponto. *Corrotinas* podem entrar, sair, e continuar em muitos pontos diferentes e *corrotinas* são declaradas com a sintaxe `async/await`.

Execute uma *corrotina* com:

- [`asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#:%7E:text=To%20cancel%20a%20running%20Task,if%20the%20Task%20was%20cancelled.) executa e retorna o resultado da *corroutina*.
- [`asyncio.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) agenda e execução de uma *corrotina* em a envolve num *[Task](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task)* retornando-o.
- [`wait`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html#await-expression) aguardando o retorno de uma *corrotina*. Só pode ser usado dentro de outra corrotina.

Como exemplo serão criada duas *corrotinas*:

- `demorada()` que é uma corrotina que poderá ou não levar *10s* para ser executada, é uma escolha aleatória decidida na linha `await asyncio.sleep(random.choice((0,10)))` que prende ou não o processamento por *10s*. Retorna um numero aleatório no intervalo `[0,65536[`.
- `main(timeout=1)` é a corrotina de nível superior. Cria uma atividade para a corrotina `demorada()` e fica no aguardo com timeout por meio do método [`asyncio.wait_for(aw, timeout)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) gerando uma exceção [`asyncio.TimeoutError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.TimeoutError) caso o tempo de execução da atividade dure mais que timeout.

Exemplo:

```
import asyncio
import random

async def demorada():
    await asyncio.sleep(random.choice((0,10)))            #Aleatoriamente sorteia se demora ou não 10s
    return random.randint(0, 65536)                       #Retorna no internalo [0,65536[
    
async def main(timeout=1):
   task = asyncio.create_task(demorada())                 #Agenda a corrotina demorada() e retorna um task. 
   try:
       await asyncio.wait_for(task, timeout)              #Aguarda a execução da Task com timeout.
   except asyncio.TimeoutError:
       task.cancel()                                      #Cancela a atividade.
       print("A função demorou demais para responder.")   #Imprime a mensagem.
   else:
       print(f"A função retornou {task.result()}")        #Imprime a mensagem com resultado de demorada()

#Faz 10 chamadas de main() com timeout 5s
for _ in range(10):
    print(">>> ",end="", flush="True")          
    asyncio.run(main(5))
```

Resultando:

```
>>> A função retornou 43258
>>> A função demorou demais para responder.
>>> A função retornou 14525
>>> A função retornou 6355
>>> A função demorou demais para responder.
>>> A função retornou 39265
>>> A função demorou demais para responder.
>>> A função retornou 39502
>>> A função demorou demais para responder.
>>> A função retornou 50657
```

Aplicando essa informação ao exemplo da pergunta basta criar um loop entorno da atividade e reiterar caso de timeout ou verificar seu resultado em tempo hábil.

```
import asyncio
import random

async def demorada():
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(0,10))            
    return random.randint(0, 65536)                       

async def main(timeout=1):
   #Abre um loop de duração indeterminada...
   while True:
       task = asyncio.create_task(demorada())          #Agenda a execução da atividade demorada
       print('Fazendo uma tentativa...')               #Imprime mensagem
       #Abre um bloco de tratamento de exceções...
       try:
           await asyncio.wait_for(task, timeout)       #Aguarda a execução da Task com timeout.       
       except asyncio.TimeoutError:                    #Havendo exceção de timeout...
           task.cancel()                               #Cancela a atividade.
           print('Time out...')                        #Imprime mensagem permanecendo no loop.
       else:
           return task.result()                        #Retorna o resultado da atividade.


req = asyncio.run(main(5))
print(f'Resultado da chamada {req}')
```

Resultando:

```
Fazendo uma tentativa...
Time out...
Fazendo uma tentativa...
Time out...
Fazendo uma tentativa...
Resultado da chamada 20864
```

Comment: Poderia informar o motivo do negativo para que eu melhore a resposta?