# Tem como fazer um cronômetro que quando zerado o tempo ele pare outros metodos em execução em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos

Minha pergunta é que.

Da pra fazer com que um laço comum em `FOR` controle o tempo de execução de outros métodos dentro da `classe`.

**Exemplo:**

**Resolva esse cálculo antes do tempo acabar!**

Estou fazendo um projeto que é um mine game em que o usuário lê uma frase e tem que escrevê-la corretamente.
Porém falta definir um tempo limite para que o usuário escreva essa frase.
Em POO, até então não encontrei uma solução viável para isso.

Corpo do codigo:

````
from time import sleep 
class Digitacao(Robot):
    def __init__(self,nome_do_usuario,nome,tipo,finalidade):
        super().__init__(nome,tipo,finalidade)
        self.__nome_do_usuario = nome_do_usuario

    def mostraDados(self):
        return f'''Olá {self.__nome_do_usuario}, 
eu sou o robô {self._nome}, 
sou um robô do tipo {self._tipo}, 
e meu objetivo é {self._finalidade}.'''

    def Digitar(self):
        palavras_erradas = []
        frases = ['viver é desenhar sem borracha','para sempre é feito de agoras','jamais se acomode com aquilo que te incomoda','não conseguimos mudar coisa alguma sem antes aceitá-la','vai ser lindo quando você entender que quase nada nessa vida merece teu desgaste']
        cont = 0
        nivel = 1
        erros = 0
        inicio = input('Digite <iniciar> para começar o programa:').lower().strip()
        if inicio == 'iniciar':
            os.system('cls')
            for i in frases:
                print(f'Nível {nivel}')
                while True:
                    print('Prepare-se')
                    sleep(3)
                    print('Agora!!!')
                    frase = input(f'Digite a frase -> {i}: ').lower().strip()
                    if frase == frases[cont]:
                        print('Parabéns você acertou a frase!')
                        cont += 1
                        nivel += 1
                        sleep(4)
                        os.system('cls')
                        break
                    else:
                        fc = frases[nivel-1].split()
                        fd = frase.split()
                        for x in range(0,len(fd)):
                            if fc[x] != fd[x]:
                                palavras_erradas.append(fd[x])
                                print(f'As palavras digitadas erradas foram:  \033[31m{palavras_erradas}\033[m')
                                erros += 1
                                palavras_erradas.clear()
                                sleep(5)
        return f'{self.__nome_do_usuario} você errou {erros} vezes!'```
````

Comment: Isso responderia? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/297721/5878